# JS in Firefox: more than three digits after comma

Tags: javascript, firefox, math

I have an issue calculating a rate in a form. This is how it works well in Chrome:

```js
$('body').on('change, keyup', 'input[data-rate]', function() {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', '.'));
    window.console.log('val:'+val);
    if (val > 0) {
        var result = val * parseFloat($(this).data('rate'));
        var rate_id = $(this).data('rate-id');
        $('input[data-ratesum-id=' + rate_id + ']').val(number_format(result, 2, ',', '.'));
    }
});

/**
     * http://locutus.io/php/strings/number_format/
     * @param number
     * @param decimals
     * @param decPoint
     * @param thousandsSep
     */
    window.number_format = function (number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {
        number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
        var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number;
        var prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals);
        var sep = (typeof thousandsSep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousandsSep;
        var dec = (typeof decPoint === 'undefined') ? '.' : decPoint;
        var s = '';
        var toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
            var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
            return '' + (Math.round(n * k) / k)
                    .toFixed(prec)
        };
        // @todo: for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
        s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
        if (s[0].length > 3) {
            s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep)
        }
        if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
            s[1] = s[1] || '';
            s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0')
        }
        return s.join(dec);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="number[19]" class="form-control" data-rate="780.00" data-rate-id="19">
<input type="text" name="sum" data-ratesum-id="19" class="form-control" disabled="">
```

When I am typing in Chrome 15,625 (german way), then in console I see this:

```
val:1
val:15
val:15.6
val:15.62
val:15.625
```

But when I do the same in FF, then I see this:

```
val:1
val:15
val:15.6
val:15.62
val:15625
```

Now you can imagine, the result is beeing calculated wrong in Firefox. Chrome gives me the right answer 12187,50, in FF I get 12187500,00
With only 2 digits after comma it would be okay, but I need the third digit.
I don't know how to fix.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Running this code snippet in Firefox I must accept that there is no error. So it is an effect in my application, but what would affect this calculation??

Comment: If you don't get the error with the above, but you do with your real application, I recommend deleting the question and following the steps described in [mcve] to zero in on the error. We can't help you fix the problem if the code above works.

Comment: I think firefox "number" input works differently in your locale to chrome ... if you make it a type="text", it seems to at least produce the expected result - e.g. when I put in 15,625 in your code ... console shows 1, 15, NaN, NaN, NaN, 15625

Comment: Jaromanda X gave me the right answer. I have changed type to text and now it works. Because of this I will not delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Right answer is the type of the input field. Changing from type="number" to type="text" solved the issue.